# MySQL length limits

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am changing my database so that certain fields can be longer. Right now they're `varchar(255)`.

Can I just increase that to `varchar(500)` or are there special rules for dealing with this and I should make them of type `TEXT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/char.html):

> The effective maximum length of a `VARCHAR` is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used.

So, yes, you can just extend your columns to be a maximum of 500 characters in length (though, you'll want to be sure your application logic doesn't expect the maximum length to be 255 characters).

---

**Edit:** see also cballou's note below about character sets.

Comment: It's worth noting that the maximum size depends on the character set used as well:

"The effective maximum number of bytes that can be stored in a VARCHAR or VARBINARY column is subject to the maximum row size of 65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns. For a VARCHAR column that stores multi-byte characters, the effective maximum number of characters is less. For example, utf8 characters can require up to three bytes per character, so a VARCHAR  column that uses the utf8 character set can be declared to be a maximum of 21,844 characters."

Answer (score 0):

Modifying to a longer varchar would be fine:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY column_name VARCHAR(500);
```